# Entity manager factory name (xyz) is already registered

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

```
    HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (XYZ) is already registered.  If entity manager will be clustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name'


11:09:28,090 WARN  [org.hibernate.ejb.internal.EntityManagerFactoryRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (XYZ) is already registered.  If entity manager will be clustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name'
11:09:28,377 INFO  [com.ust.wmi.lakshya.service.dao.UserDAO] (MSC service thread 1-1) inside getActiveUserTokens
11:09:29,219 INFO  [net.sf.ehcache.util.UpdateChecker] (net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@7e14ca96) New update(s) found: 2.4.7 [http://www.terracotta.org/confluence/display/release/Release+Notes+Ehcache+Core+2.4]. Please check http://ehcache.org for the latest version.
11:11:06,115 INFO  [com.ust.wmi.lakshya.service.dao.StoreMemberDAO] (MSC service thread 1-1) inside StoreMemberDAO()
11:11:06,240 INFO  [com.ust.wmi.lakshya.service.dao.StoreMemberDAO] (MSC service thread 1-1) inside StoreMemberDAO()
11:11:06,570 INFO  [com.ust.wmi.lakshya.service.dao.StoreMemberDAO] (MSC service thread 1-1) inside StoreMemberDAO()
11:11:06,689 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/beatPlanServices/all],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.BeatPlanRestController.getAllBeatPlan(com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceRequest)
11:11:06,691 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/beatPlanServices/all/{date}],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.BeatPlanRestController.getAllBeatPlanByDate(com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceRequest,java.lang.String)
11:11:06,692 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/collectionServices/update],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.CollectionRestController.create(com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.OrderCollectionRequest)
11:11:06,694 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/collectionServices/all],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.CollectionRestController.allOrder(com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceRequest)
11:11:06,695 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/device/logError],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.DeviceRestController.logDeviceErrors(com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.DeviceError,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
11:11:06,697 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/discussion/create],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.DiscussionsummaryController.create(com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.DiscussionRequest)
11:11:06,698 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/inventory/blockQuantity],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.InventoryBlockRestController.getQuantity(com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ItemRequest) throws java.lang.Exception
11:11:06,700 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/memberServices/addFeedBack],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.MemberRestController.addFeedBack(com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.Feedback)
11:11:06,701 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/memberServices/all/{date}],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.MemberRestController.getAllMembersByDate(com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceRequest,java.lang.String)
11:11:06,703 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/memberServices/all],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.MemberRestController.getAllActiveMembersByBDA(com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceRequest)
11:11:06,704 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/memberServices/updateMemberPhoneNo],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.MemberRestController.updateMemberPhoneNo(com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.MemberRequest)
11:11:06,706 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/orderServices/orderSummary],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.OrderRestController.orderSummary(com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceRequest)
11:11:06,708 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/orderServices/createOrder],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.OrderRestController.createOrder(com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.OrderRequest) throws java.lang.Exception
11:11:06,709 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/orderServices/getOrderDetails],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.OrderRestController.createOrder(com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.OrderDetailsRequest) throws java.lang.Exception
11:11:06,710 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/orderServices/requestOTP],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.OrderRestController.OTPRequest(com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.OrderOTP) throws java.lang.Exception
11:11:06,711 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/orderServices/orderMemberHistory],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.OrderRestController.orderMemberHistory(com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceRequest)
11:11:06,713 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/orderServices/getAvailableQty],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.OrderRestController.getAvailableQty(com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.OrderDetailsRequest) throws java.lang.Exception
11:11:06,714 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/productServices/all],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.ProductRestController.getAllProducts(com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceRequest)
11:11:06,716 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/productServices/all/{date}],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.ProductRestController.getAllProductsByDate(java.lang.String,com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceRequest)
11:11:06,717 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/promotionServices/all/{date}],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.PromotionRestController.allPromotionItemByDate(java.lang.String,com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceRequest)
11:11:06,719 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/promotionServices/all],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.PromotionRestController.allPromotionItem(com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceRequest)
11:11:06,720 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/sms/requestOTP],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.SMSController.orderOTPRequest(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
11:11:06,722 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/userServices/logout],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.UserRestController.logout(java.lang.String,com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceRequest)
11:11:06,723 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/userServices/all],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.UserRestController.getAllUsers()
11:11:06,724 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/userServices/writeLog],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.UserRestController.writeLog(com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.MobUserlogRequest)
11:11:06,726 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/userServices/creatAuthTokens],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public void com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.UserRestController.authenticateUserName()
11:11:06,727 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/userServices/authenticateUser],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.UserRestController.authenticateUserName(com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.LoginRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
11:11:06,728 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/userServices/performanceHistory],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.UserRestController.getUserPerformance(com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceRequest)
11:11:06,729 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-1) Mapped "{[/userServices/registerDevice],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.ServiceResponse com.ust.wmi.lakshya.rs.controller.UserRestController.registerDevice(com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.LoginRequest)
11:11:07,100 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver] (MSC service thread 1-1) Did not find any ViewResolvers to delegate to; please configure them using the 'viewResolvers' property on the ContentNegotiatingViewResolver
11:11:07,103 INFO  [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean] (MSC service thread 1-1) Initializing EhCache CacheManager
11:11:07,185 INFO  [com.ust.wmi.lakshya.service.dao.StoreMemberDAO] (MSC service thread 1-1) inside StoreMemberDAO()
11:11:07,230 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (MSC service thread 1-1) FrameworkServlet 'oms-rest': initialization completed in 103901 ms
11:11:07,249 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /oms-ws
11:11:07,352 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/oms-ws]] (MSC service thread 1-1) Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'oms-rest'
11:11:07,354 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'oms-rest-servlet': startup date [Mon Jan 16 11:09:23 IST 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
11:11:07,371 INFO  [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean] (MSC service thread 1-1) Shutting down EhCache CacheManager
11:11:07,395 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] (MSC service thread 1-1) Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'XYZ'
11:11:07,396 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] (MSC service thread 1-1) Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'XYZFC'
11:11:07,414 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/oms-ws]] (MSC service thread 1-1) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
11:11:07,414 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Jan 16 11:07:37 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
11:11:07,416 INFO  [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean] (MSC service thread 1-1) Shutting down EhCache CacheManager
11:11:07,463 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] (MSC service thread 1-1) Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'XYZ'
11:11:07,466 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] (MSC service thread 1-1) Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'XYZFC'
11:11:07,787 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment oms-ws.war in 162350ms
```

here i am using two entitymanager with separate of persistenceUnitName but here using database schema is same just username and password alone different.i need to use two entitymanagers with usertype wise.when i am running my application it's showing like errors.

Comment: Here's an idea ... you present some code/configuration that shows where you define that EMF. Then people have some basis for comment. Putting the full stack trace too would help

Comment: It's only a warning, not a error.